# What is the state of support for (Unicode) Indic scripts in Context?

Tags: context, unicode, scripts, indic

I have used XeTeX for typesetting a book using Unicode Malayalam. It is working perfectly and the production is fine.

Reading about ConteXt, I learn it is more suitable and flexible for book production by publishing houses. I have tried but Malayalam Unicode is not supported.

What should be done to achieve this? Is there any similar attempt successful in Tamil, Hindi,......any Unicode Indic script?

Comment: Currently, ConTeXt MkIV (luatex backed) doesnot support Indic scripts; you need to use ConTeXt MkII (xetex backend) for using Indic scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Like Aditya says, at the moment only MkII supports Indic scripts out of the box. (At least, I assume he is correct — I do not know anything about TeX + Indic scripts myself.)

If using LuaTeX instead of XeTeX is important to you, you might want to get in touch with the typesetting company [TAT Zetwerk](http://www.tatzetwerk.nl/?lang=en). I happen to know from their presentation at EuroTeX 2012 that they are currently developing an in-house solution for Devanagari in LuaTeX using OpenType features. They may be in a position to help you?

As you can see, all I can do in this answer is point at people who know more than I do. Hopefully you will eventually find an answer. Good luck in your Indic typesetting endeavours!

Comment: As a follow-up: did you manage to get in touch with TAT Zetwerk? Perhaps you could write and self-accept an answer of what you have learned about Indic typesetting with ConTeXt MkIV, for the benefit of future people looking for answers; that would definitely get my upvote. Even "It's not currently possible" would be helpful.