# ConTeXt + XeTeX (TeXLive 2012) does not work for Indic scripts like Malayalam

Tags: xetex, context

This is a follow up question to [What is the state of support for (Unicode) Indic scripts in Context?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/what-is-the-state-of-support-for-unicode-indic-scripts-in-context)

I have been trying to get texexec/mkii to work with XeTeX engine, but the resulting rendering is incorrect - reordering of Malayalam characters do not happen.

Running the following minimal example through XeLaTeX (version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9998 TeXLive 2012) gives correct output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Malayalam]{Rachana}
\begin{document}
മലയാളം \TeX ഉപയോഗിച്ച് ടൈപ്പ്സെറ്റ് ചെയ്തത്
\end{document}
```

Correct rendering screenshot here:

[image]

The same with ConTeXt "texexec --xetex" (version ConTeXt ver: 2012.05.30 11:26 MKII fmt: 2013.1.1 int: english/english) results in incorrect rendering.

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\setmainfont[Rachana]
\starttext
മലയാളം \TeX ഉപയോഗിച്ച് ടൈപ്പ്സെറ്റ് ചെയ്തത്
\stoptext
```

Incorrect rendering screenshot: [image]

What possibly am I missing? The font used is Rachana, which can be found from Savannah download page (version 5.0.1)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Simplefonts module only works for MkIV. For xetex, you need to define typescripts using traditional methods.

Comment: @Aditya: Could you explain a little more or give a pointer on how to do that for Indic scripts? AFAIU, typescripts are using the .tfm font format rather than otf/ttf.

Comment: Documentation here http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TypeScripts says that typescripts will not work with XeTeX. I followed the guide here http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_XeTeX using 'definetypeface' and 'setupbodyfont' but the rendering is incorrect.

Comment: Look at `type-*.mkii` files in the distribution for examples of typescripts. To get correct rendering of indic scripts, you need to set up appropriate font features(the `mapping=...` part in the Typescripts page on the wiki), but I do not know what these font mappings are. The easiest way to proceed is to look at an xetex example in plain tex; that should work out of the box with xetex as well. Otherwise, post to the context mailing list where someone familiar with using indic scripts with xetex might be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a font feature set to specify font script, language or any other feature you want to use.

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\definefontfeature[malayalam][script=mlym]
\setmainfont[Rachana][features=malayalam]
\starttext
മലയാളം \TeX ഉപയോഗിച്ച് ടൈപ്പ്സെറ് 
\stoptext
```

`features=malayalam` can be passed to typescripts as well, in place of `features=default` in the [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_XeTeX). All features passed to `\definefontfeature` are in key value syntax, so instead of `+liga;-kern` in the raw XeTeX syntax, ConTeXt uses `liga=yes,kern=no`, but the tags are the same (no user friendly names as in `fontspec`).

Comment: Thank you Khaled!!!
Defining features indeed produce the correct rendering.